# How to show alert when enter key pressed

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to get the alert message but it doesn't show at all. It only shows if I deleted (event) from : `function myFunction(event)`.

Can you help me fix it so it can show the alert box when I type less than three letters? Here's the code that I'm stuck with :

```js
function myFunction(input, e) {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  if (filter.length < 3 && e.key === "Enter") {
    alert(
      "Search is going to work only if the phrase contains at least 3 characters."
    );
    return;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this, event)" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve it?

edited: I added the html code to show more about the problem.

Comment: You don't send the `event` object into the function. Change to `onkeyup="myFunction(event)"`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev when I delete the event from myFunction() and add it to onkeyup="myFunction(event)" the first part of if statement (filter.length < 3) doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See working example.

```js
function myFunction(input, e) {
  var filter, table, tr, td, i;
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (var i = 0, t; t = tr[i]; ++i) {
    if (t.className !== 'header')
      t.style.display = 'none'
  }
  //start search only after Enter pressed
  if (e.key !== 'Enter')
    return;
  //and length >=3
  if (filter.length < 3) {
    alert("Search is going to work only if the phrase contains at least 3 characters.");
    return;
  }
  //continue with search here
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this, event)" placeholder="Example: Mauro, etc." />
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @AlexKurdryashev your code works but how can I stop the result from showing what i'm searching if the letters were less than 3 ? the code works fine with the alert, but when I start typing the first letter, the search result starts to appear. I want the search result to appear only when I start to type the third letter and by the way, thank you for the effort and time :)

Comment: Add `return` just after `alert` and start your search logic when length check pass. See updated answer.

Comment: @AlexKurdyashev I tried it again with return as you suggested , but it still shows the result after typing the first letter :(

Comment: Show your full code. I have no cue from your snippet where anything else occur.

Comment: See updated answer. You can accept it if it works as expected.

Comment: thank you very much for the effort and time you put to help me :) your code works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Catch the event and get the keyCode if it is equal to 13 then is the enter key

```
e.key === 13
```

Comment: `.keyCode` is deprecated. `.key` is OK. The problem is different. See my comment above.

Comment: `e.keyCode` is a depriciated method. See the [The MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) for more info.